# hg + remove bookmark and all changes

Tags: mercurial

I would like to abandon all changes in my bookmark and delete the bookmark itself. 
I tried the instructions under: [Mercurial - How to discard all local changes including to unversioned files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4957721/mercurial-how-to-discard-all-local-changes-including-to-unversioned-files) 
i.e `hg --revert .` 
In addition, I looked at [Bookmarks](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Bookmarks) where it says that the delete feature still leaves changed files. How do I go to a state where I can start afresh from the contents of the remote repository?

Answer (score 2):

A bookmark is separate from the changes in the changeset. You can modify or delete the bookmark, and it keeps the changeset untouched. A physical bookmark is a good analogy: you can move it from page to page or remove it completely without altering the book contents - it's just a pointer to a page.

If you have committed the changes already into a changeset, you want to either [back them out](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Backout) or [strip](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/StripExtension) them.

If you just want to start from the remote, delete your repository and re-clone it.